# Conflict between S3 notification and Lambda permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the following error when trying to configure S3 notifications right after creating a Lambda function:

```
InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
```

This is my terraform code (I cut and renamed a few pieces for better understanding) - this works fine:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  s3_bucket                      = var.lambda_storage_bucket
  s3_key                         = var.lambda_package_path
  source_code_hash               = data.aws_s3_object.lambda_checksum.body
  role                           = aws_iam_role.my_lambda_role.arn
  memory_size                    = "128"
  timeout                        = 10
  reserved_concurrent_executions = -1
  publish                        = true
  ...
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "my_lambda_role" {
  name_prefix        = "${var.environment}-my_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trust_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "basic_lambda_execution" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.aws_lambda_vpc_access_execution_role_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_lambda_policy" {
  name_prefix = "${var.environment}-my_lambda_policy"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_lambda_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "my_lambda_policy_attachment" {
  name       = "my_lambda-policy-attachment"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.my_lambda_policy.arn

  roles = [
    aws_iam_role.my_lambda_role.name,
  ]
}
```

Outputs this:

```
output "lambda_arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda.qualified_arn
}

output "function_name" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda.function_name
}
```

And the error comes from this module:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  for_each      = var.lambda_invoke_permission
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = each.value
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket}"
}

ERROR HERE --> resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = var.bucket

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = var.lambda_filters
    iterator = it

    content {
      lambda_function_arn = it.value.lambda_function_arn
      events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
      filter_prefix       = it.value.prefix
      filter_suffix       = it.value.suffix
    }
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
}
```

Same error was reported here: [Terraform - Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010382/terraform-error-putting-s3-notification-configuration-invalidargument-unable)

Basically they added a 3 seconds sleep before configuring s3 notifications but I wonder if that's the right thing to do.

Did anyone had similar experience?

Comment: Are there any bucket policies applied to the S3 bucket in quesiton?

Comment: @MarkoE no policy to display =P

Comment: And there is a lambda permission also (I shared in the question)

Comment: From what I have found, it could be an issue with some kind of permissions. So that's where I would look at.

Comment: I should probably add Lambda inside depends_on and not only the permission resource I believe

Comment: Also, are you creating the bucket outside of the module for notifications?

Comment: @MarkoE exactly, outside of this piece

Comment: So the bucket name is passed to the module as an output from another module?

Comment: It goes as a string variable to the module actually. Bucket already exists and it was created outside terraform.